# How to construct a filter to detect diagonal edges

Tags: image-processing

I am trying to Construct a filter that detect diagonal edges in a given matrix of an image in the direction of a vector (1,1). Can someone point me to how do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a diagonal variant of the Sobel filter, of the form:

```
[[2  1  0],
 [1  0 -1],
 [0 -1 -2]]
```